# logical error in the execution of merge sort

Tags: python

my mergesort code is giving 0's as the members of the sorted array
what is the reason for such output?

```
PS C:\Users\admin\Desktop\python> python m.py
4 0 6 1 5 2 3
the  soerted array is [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
PS C:\Users\admin\Desktop\python>
```

the code is as follows

```
    g = []
    n = q-p+1
    m = r-q
    b = [0]*(n)
    c = [0]*(m)
    for i in range(0, n):
        b.append(a[i+p])
    for j in range(0, m):
        c.append(a[q+1+j])
    b.append(math.inf)
    c.append(math.inf)
    i = 0
    j = 0

    for k in range(p, r+1):
        if b[i] < c[j]:
            g.append(b[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            g.append(c[j])
            j += 1

    return g


def mergesort(a, p, r):
    if p < r:
        q = (p+r)//2
        mergesort(a, p, q)
        mergesort(a, q+1, r)
        return merge(a, p, q, r)


a = [4, 0, 6, 1, 5, 2, 3]
n = len(a)
print(*a, sep=" ")
print("the  sorted array is", mergesort(a, 0, n-1))
```

is there any other better way to write the driver code for this program

Comment: Thats because, You are implementing it incorrectly.

Comment: You should implement mergesort in a more `pythonic` way.

Comment: I know their are better ways to implement mergesort but, I just wanted to know that why didn't this code work?

Answer (score 0):

This code contains quite a lot of errors. For example, 
        mergesort(a, p, q) 
        mergesort(a, q+1, r) 
The returned value of these two lines are never used.

```
b = [0]*(n)
c = [0]*(m)
```

Here you fill the two lists with 0s, then you append new values at the end of the lists, while these 0s will only make sure your returned values are nothing but 0s.